# I am trying to access room_type_info from json data but unable to do in swift

Tags: json, swift

JSON:

```
"results" : [ {
    "property_code" : "WYBOSCHH",
    "property_name" : "Wyndham Boston Chelsea",
    "location" : {
      "latitude" : 42.39795,
      "longitude" : -71.03977
    },
    "address" : {
      "line1" : "201 Everett Avenue",
      "city" : "Chelsea",
      "region" : "MA",
      "postal_code" : "02150-1816",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "total_price" : {
      "amount" : "287.30",
      "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "min_daily_rate" : {
      "amount" : "71.82",
      "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "contacts" : [ {
      "type" : "PHONE",
      "detail" : "1-617-8842900"
    }, {
      "type" : "FAX",
      "detail" : "1-617-8847888"
    } ],
    "amenities" : [ {
      "amenity" : "ICE_MACHINE",
      "ota_code" : 52,
      "description" : "Ice machine"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "RESTAURANT",
      "ota_code" : 76,
      "description" : "Restaurant"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "BABY_SITTING",
      "ota_code" : 8,
      "description" : "Baby sitting"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "BEAUTY_SALON",
      "ota_code" : 107,
      "description" : "Beauty shop/salon"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "ELEVATORS",
      "ota_code" : 33,
      "description" : "Elevators"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "INTERNET_PUBLIC_AREAS",
      "ota_code" : 178,
      "description" : "Internet access in public areas"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "JACUZZI",
      "ota_code" : 55,
      "description" : "Jacuzzi"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "LAUNDRY_SERVICE",
      "ota_code" : 58,
      "description" : "Laundry/Valet service"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "PARKING",
      "ota_code" : 68,
      "description" : "Parking"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "LOUNGE_BARS",
      "ota_code" : 165,
      "description" : "Lounges/bars"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "POOL",
      "ota_code" : 71,
      "description" : "Pool"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "OUTDOOR_POOL",
      "ota_code" : 66,
      "description" : "Outdoor pool"
    } ],
    "awards" : [ {
      "provider" : "Local Star Rating",
      "rating" : "3"
    }, {
      "provider" : "AAA",
      "rating" : "3"
    } ],
    "images" : [ {
      "category" : "MAIN_IMAGE",
      "width" : 70,
      "height" : 70,
      "url" : "http://multimediarepository.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/5811669CC5364943965EC9FB3D56642C/A"
    }, {
      "category" : "MAIN_IMAGE",
      "width" : 480,
      "height" : 260,
      "url" : "http://multimediarepository.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/5811669CC5364943965EC9FB3D56642C/J"
    } ],
    "rooms" : [ {
      "booking_code" : "N2DA01",
      "room_type_code" : "N2D",
      "rate_plan_code" : "A01",
      "total_amount" : {
        "amount" : "287.30",
        "currency" : "USD"
      },
      "rates" : [ {
        "start_date" : "2016-03-14",
        "end_date" : "2016-03-16",
        "currency_code" : "USD",
        "price" : 143.65
      } ],
      "descriptions" : [ "PAY NOW GET 200 BONUS POINTS", "2 DOUBLE BED ROOM, WIFI, 32 INCH FLAT SCREEN", "TV." ],
      "room_type_info" : {
        "room_type" : "Non-smoking",
        "bed_type" : "Double",
        "number_of_beds" : "2"
      },
      "rate_type_code" : "A01"
    } ],
    "_links" : {
      "more_rooms_at_this_hotel" : {
        "href" : "http://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/hotels/WYBOSCHH?apikey=zO8hvuhC5ejQBwJgMcGzS19fGpExrRuQ&check_in=2016-03-14&check_out=2016-03-16"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "property_code" : "HYBOSHHS",
    "property_name" : "Hyatt Regency Boston Harbor",
    "location" : {
      "latitude" : 42.35914,
      "longitude" : -71.02742
    },
    "address" : {
      "line1" : "101 Harborside Dr",
      "city" : "Boston",
      "region" : "MA",
      "postal_code" : "02128",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "total_price" : {
      "amount" : "297.44",
      "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "min_daily_rate" : {
      "amount" : "139.92",
      "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "contacts" : [ {
      "type" : "PHONE",
      "detail" : "1-617-568-1234"
    }, {
      "type" : "FAX",
      "detail" : "1-617-567-8856"
    } ],
    "amenities" : [ {
      "amenity" : "COFFEE_SHOP",
      "ota_code" : 20,
      "description" : "Coffee shop"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "RESTAURANT",
      "ota_code" : 76,
      "description" : "Restaurant"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "ACCESSIBLE_FACILITIES",
      "ota_code" : 47,
      "description" : "Accessible facilities"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "BABY_SITTING",
      "ota_code" : 8,
      "description" : "Baby sitting"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "CAR_RENTAL",
      "ota_code" : 15,
      "description" : "Car rental desk"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "CHILDREN_WELCOME",
      "ota_code" : 218,
      "description" : "Children welcome"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "ELEVATORS",
      "ota_code" : 33,
      "description" : "Elevators"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "CURRENCY_EXCHANGE",
      "ota_code" : 26,
      "description" : "Currency exchange"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "GIFT_SHOP",
      "ota_code" : 45,
      "description" : "Gift/News stand"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "FREE_HIGH_SPEED_INTERNET",
      "ota_code" : 222,
      "description" : "Free high speed internet connection"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "INTERNET_PUBLIC_AREAS",
      "ota_code" : 178,
      "description" : "Internet access in public areas"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "PARKING",
      "ota_code" : 68,
      "description" : "Parking"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "PETS_ALLOWED",
      "ota_code" : 224,
      "description" : "Pets allowed"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "VALET_PARKING",
      "ota_code" : 97,
      "description" : "Valet parking "
    }, {
      "amenity" : "LOUNGE_BARS",
      "ota_code" : 165,
      "description" : "Lounges/bars"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "LOUNGE_BARS",
      "ota_code" : 165,
      "description" : "Lounges/bars"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "ROOM_SERVICE",
      "ota_code" : 77,
      "description" : "Room service"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "SAFE_DEPOSIT_BOX",
      "ota_code" : 78,
      "description" : "Safe deposit box"
    }, {
      "amenity" : "BALLROOM",
      "ota_code" : 191,
      "description" : "Ballroom"
    } ],
    "awards" : [ ],
    "images" : [ {
      "category" : "MAIN_IMAGE",
      "width" : 70,
      "height" : 70,
      "url" : "http://multimediarepository.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/AE3C4B469985434AB8E48B23FD4A50CD/A"
    }, {
      "category" : "MAIN_IMAGE",
      "width" : 320,
      "height" : 480,
      "url" : "http://multimediarepository.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/AE3C4B469985434AB8E48B23FD4A50CD/J"
    } ],
    "rooms" : [ {
      "booking_code" : "KNGADPR",
      "room_type_code" : "A1K",
      "rate_plan_code" : "***",
      "total_amount" : {
        "amount" : "297.44",
        "currency" : "USD"
      },
      "rates" : [ {
        "start_date" : "2016-03-14",
        "end_date" : "2016-03-15",
        "currency_code" : "USD",
        "price" : 139.92
      }, {
        "start_date" : "2016-03-15",
        "end_date" : "2016-03-16",
        "currency_code" : "USD",
        "price" : 157.52
      } ],
      "descriptions" : [ "ADV PURCHASE* AVIATION KING", "1 KING BED: COFFEE MAKER:DATAPORT:" ],
      "room_type_info" : {
        "room_type" : "Room with bath - Superior",
        "bed_type" : "King",
        "number_of_beds" : "1"
      },
      "rate_type_code" : "***"
    } ],
    "_links" : {
      "more_rooms_at_this_hotel" : {
        "href" : "http://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/hotels/HYBOSHHS?apikey=zO8hvuhC5ejQBwJgMcGzS19fGpExrRuQ&check_in=2016-03-14&check_out=2016-03-16"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Code:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error) in

    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error")
    }
    else {
        do {
            let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
            let results = fetchedData["results"]! as! NSArray

            for eachFetchedHotel in results {
                let eachHotel = eachFetchedHotel as! [String: Any]
                let hotel_name = eachHotel["property_name"] as! String

                for eachRoomInfo in eachHotel["rooms"] {
                    //                            if let roomTypeInfo = eachRoomInfo["room_type_info"] as! Int{
                    //                                let occupancy_type = roomTypeInfo["number_of_beds"] as! Int
                    //                            }
                    for item in eachRoomInfo["room_type_info"]{
                        let occupancy_type = item["number_of_beds"]
                    }
                }


                //                        let occupanct_type = eachHotel["rooms"]["room_type_info"]["number_of_beds"] as! Int

                let price = eachHotel["total_price.currency" + "total_price.amount"] as! Int
                let image = eachHotel["images.url"] as! NSData
                self.fetchedHotelData.append(Room(name: hotel_name, occupancy: occupancy_type, price: price, vacant_status: true, image: image))
            }
            print(self.fetchedHotelData)
        }

        catch{
            print("Error 2")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see a question here, can you describe your problem?

Comment: I am trying to parse the json data in a temporary array but unable to do so for number_of_beds attribute

Comment: OK, could you add that information to the question along with details of any errors you are getting and hopefully someone will be able to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you using Alamofire (a powerful networking framework) and SwiftyJSON (for parsing JSON), they are very popular for iOS development.

With SwiftyJSON, you do not need to handle the error or worry about nested JSON, just do something like:

```
json["data"]["room_type_infor"].stringValue.
```